# How can I generate a password from SHA3-512 hash value?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, python-3.7, sha, brute-force

I am trying to figure out the password for this SHA3-512 hash value: 11af05af85d7656ee0f2e3260760bccdc2af88dee449f682ab2e367003856166edc045c4164a4d543ea4a43d6dd022d3c290866f2d2a7a92a38400bd3a5f7ab0.
The issue I am having is that when I run my code it still returns the hash value. My question is what do I need to change in my code to produce the password? Here are some screenshots of the results from running my code. [image]

```
import itertools
import time
import hashlib
from binascii import hexlify
import shutil
import os

data = input("Enter Password:")
data1 = data.encode('utf-8')
sha3_512 = hashlib.sha3_512(data1)
sha3_512_digest = sha3_512.digest()
sha3_512_hex_digest = sha3_512.hexdigest()
print(sha3_512_hex_digest)


# Function to brute force the password
def tryPassword(passwordSet):
    start = time.time()
 
    # Allowed characters in the password
    chars = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]}|:;'\",<.>/?"
    
    attempts = 0

    for value in range(1, 800):
        # Build up a string to test against, character by character
        for letter in itertools.product(chars, repeat=value):
            attempts += 1
            letter = ''.join(letter)

            #if the string we are building matches the password given to us, return from the function
            if letter == passwordSet:
                end = time.time()
                distance = end - start
                return (attempts, distance)



tries, timeAmount = tryPassword(data)
print("The password %s was cracked in %s tries and %s seconds!" % (data, tries, timeAmount))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently doesn't use the hash to find the password. Instead you currently iterate over your alphabet to match the password that you've also put in.

You need to pass in the hashed password instead of the actual password into your `tryPassword` function. Additionally, inside of the function, you need to hash your generated password candidate and compare it to the passed in hash.

Here is the full code. I've changed some variable names to make it clear what they are.

```
import itertools
import time
import hashlib
from binascii import hexlify
import shutil
import os

pw = input("Enter Password:")
pw = pw.encode('utf-8')
pwHashHex = hashlib.sha3_512(pw).hexdigest()
print(pwHashHex)


# Function to brute force the password
def tryPassword(pwHashHex):
    start = time.time()
 
    # Allowed characters in the password
    alphabet = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]}|:;'\",<.>/?"
    
    attempts = 0

    for value in range(1, 800):
        # Build up a string to test against, character by character
        for pwCandidate in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=value):
            attempts += 1
            pwCandidate = ''.join(pwCandidate)

            #if the string we are building matches the password given to us, return from the function
            if hashlib.sha3_512(pwCandidate).hexdigest() == pwHashHex:
                end = time.time()
                distance = end - start
                return (pwCandidate, attempts, distance)

pwFound, tries, timeAmount = tryPassword(pwHashHex)
print("The password %s was cracked in %s tries and %s seconds!" % (pwFound, tries, timeAmount))
```