# Generate a password from SHA3-512 hash value

Tags: python, hash, sha, brute-force

I'm new to python, currently taking an IT as a master's degree. I'm working on decoding a password from a hash value.

This is how I'm currently set up. I know it's wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import itertools
import time
from Crypto.Hash import SHA3_512

# Function to brute force the password
def tryPassword(passwordSet):
    start = time.time()

    # Allowed characters in the password
    chars = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]}|:;'\",<.>/?"
    
    attempts = 0

    for value in range(1, 9):
        # Build up a string to test against, character by character
        for letter in itertools.product(chars, repeat=value):
            attempts += 1
            letter = ''.join(letter)
            hash_object = SHA3_512.new()
            hash_object.update((letter).encode("utf-8"))

            tmp_hash = hash_object.hexdigest()
            print(tmp_hash)

            #if the string we are building matches the password given to us, return from the function
            if tmp_hash == passwordSet:
                end = time.time()
                distance = end - start
                return (attempts, distance)


password = input("Password >")
tries, timeAmount, = tryPassword(password)
print("The password %s was cracked in %s tries and %s seconds!" % (password, tries, timeAmount))
```

Comment: the function needs to take the hashed password as a parameter. Then after it generates a password in the loop, it has to hash it and compare to the parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate a password from SHA3-512 hash value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082640/how-can-i-generate-a-password-from-sha3-512-hash-value)

Answer (score 0):

Since the purpose is to crack a hashed password, that's what should be the parameter to the function, not a plain-text password.

Then in the loop it needs to hash each candidate password, and compare the hash to the input.

```
import itertools
import time
from Crypto.Hash import SHA3_512

def hash_password(password):
    hash_object = SHA3_512.new()
    hash_object.update(password.encode("utf-8"))
    return hash_object.hexdigest()

def tryPassword(hashed_pass):
    start = time.time()

    # Allowed characters in the password
    chars = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]}|:;'\",<.>/?"
    
    attempts = 0

    for value in range(1, 9):
        # Build up a string to test against, character by character
        for letter in itertools.product(chars, repeat=value):
            attempts += 1
            candidate = ''.join(letter)

            #if the string we are building matches the password given to us, return from the function
            if hash_password(candidate) == hashed_pass:
                end = time.time()
                distance = end - start
                return (attempts, distance, password)

password = input("Password > ")
tmp_hash = hash_password(password)

tries, timeAmount, found_password = tryPassword(tmp_hash)
print("The password %s was cracked in %s tries and %s seconds!" % (found_password, tries, timeAmount))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! I ran the program to crack this password below:
11af05af85d7656ee0f2e3260760bccdc2af88dee449f682ab2e367003856166edc045c4164a4d543ea4a43d6dd022d3c290866f2d2a7a92a38400bd3a5f7ab0
This is the output which does not show me the password:
The password 11af05af85d7656ee0f2e3260760bccdc2af88dee449f682ab2e367003856166edc045c4164a4d543ea4a43d6dd022d3c290866f2d2a7a92a38400bd3a5f7ab0 was cracked in 900920 tries and 1558.3180966377258 seconds!

Comment: The function doesn't return the candidate that matched, it just returns the number of attempts and the time.

Comment: You could use `return attempts, distance, candidate`

Comment: I cant get that program to run correctly. I've updated my original code which is able to produce the same output. How do I update it to tell me the password found?

Comment: Please don't change the question, now my answer has no context. If you want to show what you tried, add it to the question but leave the original code alone.

Comment: It works here: https://ideone.com/JFfxWU I had to switch to MD5 because it couldn't find SHA3_512, but the algorithm is the same regardless of the hash function.